# Copy Plesk MySql database back-up to new instance

Tags: mysql, plesk

I've got a CentOS 5.7 server, running Plesk (11.5.30) and MySql (5.1). There's a Plesk nightly backup of the site, which is approx 5GB (db and content).

One of the site users has deleted all their content this morning, so I'm intending to get the backup database running as a separate entity, then go through their content and copy it across to the live system.

Is there a simple/quick way of restoring the backup to a new, empty database without having to download the whole thing and re-upload it?

eta: [These are the instructions](http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/115065) from Parallels, but they involve downloading the whole backup first. Would dearly love to avoid this step

Answer (score 0):

You can restore MySQL DB through command line. First try to find mysql database backup file in your backup directory(**/var/lib/psa/dumps**) and than try to restore your MySQL database backup file to empty database using following command

```
mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` DB-NAME < SQLFILE-NAME
```